# Delegates not working in another module

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, delegates

Running into an odd issue with tasks and delegates.  Code in question is running under dotNET 4.5.1, VS2013. On the form's code I have a sub that updates a grid, it checks to see if an invoke is required, and if it is it calls a delegate.  When a task runs that's called in the same module, it works as expected, no problems.  Threaded or not, the grid updates properly.

However, if the same thing is called from another module, the delegate never gets called and the visual component doesn't get updated.  Just a watered down bit of pseudocode to clarify..

In the form's module:

```
Private Delegate Sub DoWhateverDelegate(ByVal _____)
Public Sub DoWhatever(ByVal _____)
    If MyComponent.InvokeReqired
        Dim Delegated As New DoWhateverDelegate(AddressOf DoWhatever)
        Debug.Print("The delegate fired")
        Invoke(Delegated, _____)
    Else
        ' .. carry on as usual ..
    End If
End Sub
```

Elsewhere....

```
Task.Run(Sub()
             ' .. various things I'd rather not block the UI thread with ..
             DoWhatever()
         End Sub)
```

Works fine.  I can do Task.Run_*_* that calls DoWhatever and it's all happy and good.  However if I create a task in another module and call DoWhatever, it doesn't fire the delegate and that visual component doesn't update.  The code is identical, in the same module it works, in another module it does not.

I'm probably missing something blatantly obvious.. anyone care to point out my mistake?  Thanks.

Edit -- just to clarify, that other module is just code, there's only one form in the entire solution. It's created at program startup automatically, there is no other form creation going on.

Comment: Try `MyComponent.Invoke(Delegated, ...)` BTW: You are not using things like `Form1` etc, but `f = new Form1`, are you? Because the "default instance" is thread-specific ...

Comment: Tried it, no effect.  It's still calling the "non-delegated" code, which does run but the visual component doesn't update.  The only reason I have the code in various modules is for the sake of organization.. I could always just move it back into the one module where it does work... I'm just really curious as to why it's not working as expected.  As far as the form itself goes, it's being created at startup, the "main form", not being created manually.

Comment: I think both the delegate and the target method of the delegate must be public for this to work.

Comment: Tried making the delegate public as well, still do good.  I tried another test.  On the main form, I do a task.run.  That task first adds something to the grid via DoWhatever, that works as expected.  Then it calls a sub in another module that does the exact same thing, that does not work.  The only difference is that it's in another module.. namespaces shouldn't affect threading and delegates should it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be a thread-specific issue. Check this:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    foo.DoSomething()

End Sub
End Class
```

The class with the delegate:

```
Public Class foo

Public Shared Sub DoSomething()
    Task.Run(Sub() UpdateText())
End Sub

Public Delegate Sub UpdateTextDelegate()
Public Shared Sub UpdateText()

    Dim f = Form1
    'Dim f As Form1 = Application.OpenForms("Form1")

    If f.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim d As UpdateTextDelegate = AddressOf UpdateText
        f.Invoke(d)
    Else
        f.TextBox1.Text = "Hi"
    End If

End Sub

End Class
```

Run the code and the textbox will not be updated. Use the second `f=....` (that one that take a reference from OpenForms) and it will be updated.
If you just try to access the `default instance` and you are outside the UI-thread, a new instance of the form will be created. That means, the content IS updated, but because that form is not shown, you will not see it.

**NOTE** I do **NOT** advise to solve your problem, by using `OpenForms`. I'd advise to correctly instantiate forms!

Add a new module/class to your code:

```
Module Startup

Public MyForm1 As Form1

Public Sub main()

    MyForm1 = New Form1
    Application.Run(MyForm1)

End Sub

End Module
```

Go to project properties -> application. Disable application framework and choose `Sub Main` as your start object. In the app, access your form via `MyForm1` - or whatever you want to name it. Problem should be gone then.

Comment: That it.  See below, was surprised to see a "mystery form" being created.  Adjusted the code accordingly to use that instance, and it's now working.  Thanks ;)

Comment: Bumping this old thread. May I ask, what is the downside of using OpenForms? I tried your recommended solution in my application, but I have some backgroundworkers in place on my Form1 that throw nullreference exceptions now if I try to reach them with e.g. "If BGWorker.IsBusy".